# Stan. Using target += syntax

Tags: bayesian, stan

I'm starting to learn Stan.

Could anyone explain when and how to use syntax such as... ?

```
target +=
```

instead of just:

```
y ~ normal(mu, sigma)
```

For example in Stan manual you can find the following example.

```
model {
real ps[K]; // temp for log component densities
sigma ~ cauchy(0, 2.5);
mu ~ normal(0, 10);
for (n in 1:N) {
for (k in 1:K) {
ps[k] = log(theta[k])
+ normal_lpdf(y[n] | mu[k], sigma[k]);
}
target += log_sum_exp(ps);
}
}
```

I think the target line increases the target value, that I think it's the logarithm of the posterior density.
But the posterior density for what parameter?

When is it updated and initialized?

After Stan finishes (and converges), how do you access its value and how I use it?

Other examples:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> J;          // number of schools 
  real y[J];               // estimated treatment effects
  real<lower=0> sigma[J];  // s.e. of effect estimates 
}
parameters {
  real mu; 
  real<lower=0> tau;
  vector[J] eta;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[J] theta;
  theta = mu + tau * eta;
}
model {
  target += normal_lpdf(eta | 0, 1);
  target += normal_lpdf(y | theta, sigma);
}
```

the example above uses target twice instead of just once.

another example.

```
data {
int<lower=0> N;
vector[N] y;
}
parameters {
real mu;
real<lower=0> sigma_sq;
vector<lower=-0.5, upper=0.5>[N] y_err;
}
transformed parameters {
real<lower=0> sigma;
vector[N] z;
sigma = sqrt(sigma_sq);
z = y + y_err;
}
model {
target += -2 * log(sigma);
z ~ normal(mu, sigma);
}
```

This last example even mixes both methods.

To do it even more difficult I've read that

```
y ~ normal(0,1);
```

has the same effect than

```
increment_log_prob(normal_log(y,0,1));
```

Could anyone explain why, please?

Could anyone provide a simple example written in two different ways, with "target +=" and in the regular simpler "y ~" way, please?

Regards

Comment: It's clear that you have a broad set of questions about eventually getting to the point of using rstan, but you should first learn STAN and only after that is done should you think about extending that perspective to translating to a different syntactic programming environment. Narrow your question if you don't want it closed.

Comment: My question is just "How and why to use target += ?" .
The rest are just examples and some explanations.

Comment: So then, don't include extraneous material and tags to languages and packages that are not in question.

Comment: OK, deleted the tags.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The syntax

```
target += u;
```

adds u to the target log density.

The target density is the density from which the sampler samples and it needs to be equal to the joint density of all the parameters given the data up to a constant (which is usually achieved via Bayes's rule by coding as the joint density of parameters and modeled data up to a constant).  You access it as lp__ in the posterior, but be careful, as it also contains the Jacobians arising from the constraints and drops constants in sampling statements---you do not want to use it for model comparison.

From a sampling perspective, writing

```
target += normal_lpdf(y | mu, sigma);
```

has the same effect as

```
y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
```

The _lpdf signals it's the log probability density function for the normal, which is implicit in the sampling notation.  The sampling notation is just shorthand for the target += syntax, and in addition, drops constant terms in the log density.

It's explained in the statements section of the language reference (the second part of the manual) and used in multiple examples through the programmer's guide (the first part of the manual).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation.  Why the y ~ syntax doesn't use addition but the target += does?

Comment: And what about using two "target +=" lines in the same model? Some examples do it.

Comment: The log density is an ongoing sum and target += just increments it.  You can have as many ~ statements as you want and as many target += statements as you want.

Comment: The += notation follows usual programming language conventions (though the variable target is built in) whereas the sampling statement notation follows BUGS and statistical notation.

Comment: The "target += " version is always needed when dealing with discrete variables because is the only way to marginalize them out, isn't it?

Comment: [This](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_29/reference-manual/increment-log-prob.html) is a useful resource too

Answer (score 6):

I am just starting to learn Stan and Bayesian statistics, and mainly rely on John Kruschke's book ["Doing Bayesian Data Analysis"](https://www.elsevier.com/books/doing-bayesian-data-analysis/kruschke/978-0-12-405888-0). Here, in chapter 14.3.3, he explains:

> Thus, the essence of computation in Stan is dealing with the logarithm
> of the posterior probability density and its gradient; there is no
> direct random sampling of parameters from distributions.

As a result (still rephrasing Kruschke), a

> model [...] like `y ∼ normal(mu,sigma)` [actuallly] means to multiply the current posterior probability by the density of the normal distribution at the datum value y.

Following logarithm calculation rules, this multiplication is equal to add the log probability density of a given data `y` to the current log-probability. (`log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b)`, hence the equality of multiplication and sum).

I concede that I don't grasp the full implications of that, but I think it points into the right direction into what, mathematically speaking, the `targer +=` does.